# hierarchical clustering output in spss to determine no of clusters?

Tags: cluster-analysis, spss, hierarchical-clustering

I have applied hierarchical(agglomerative) clustering in SPSS on my 100 records dataset.
The rule says that 'where the distance coefficients makes the larger jumb that point determines the no of clusters.

Formula: no of cases - steps of elbow= no of clusters
I am following this tutorial 'http://www.mvsolution.com/wp-content/uploads/SPSS-Tutorial-Cluster-Analysis.pdf'. The problem is that in my output there is no larger jumb in distance coefficient then how can I determine value of k from this?

When I calculated the change in distance coefficient, it comes out:

### 640-609= 31

### 671-640=31

### 711-671=40

### 755-711=44

### 800-755=45

### 846-800=46

900-846=54

962-900=62

1025-962=63

1091-1025=66

1160-1091=69

1233-1160=73

1305-1233=72

1379-1305=74

1460-1379=81

1543-1460=83

1630-1543=87

1728-1630=98

I need the value of k to apply kmeans..

Comment: consider posting this question in http://stats.stackexchange.com/ also

Answer (score 0):

On a data set that only consists of **a single cluster** (or when the distance function doens't really work), **there will (usually) be no knee**.

Why don't you first get acquainted to hierarchical clustering by trying it out on a number of toy data sets? Try it on a clustered 2D data set, a uniform 2d dataset, and a 2d data set with a single gaussian cluster, to get a feeling of how these plots behave.

Then try the same data sets, but de-normalize them, by scaling one dimension with 10000. Badly normalized data can completely hide the structure that you are interested in!

Comment: I have know how of hierarchical clustering. I have read some tutorials related to it. Now when I applied it on my data set I got this problem in output. Besides my data set is denormalize. I am new to clustering, suggest me some straight forward technique to determine no of clusters. I am using rapidminer and weka.